# How to find the right line to get the input style?

Tags: html, input, types, sass

In which position in the .scss file should I put the input[type="caption"] (and detail) to get the effect triggered:

**example.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="serviceForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
    <table cellspacing="0" class="simple">
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td> 
                <input formControlName="title" type="title" [value]="service.title">
             </td>
             <td>
                <input formControlName="caption" type="caption" [value]="service.caption">
                <input formControlName="detail" type="detail" [value]="service.detail">
             </td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

**example.scss**

```
form {
   .simple{ 
       tbody {
         tr {
           td {
              input[type="title"] {
                 ...(This works)
              }
              input[type="caption"] {
                 ...(Not working)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Your code work fine on my side, you probably have something else overriding the styles of `type="caption"`

Comment: I found it! Thx!